# Enable/Disable handler mappings in 2008 R2 and IIS7 using Powershell 3.0

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0

I'm attempting to automate the configuration of a Web server using powershell 3.0. OS is 2008 R2 SP1.

My goal is to make this as automated as possible. How do I enable the ISAPI-dll handler mapping in IIS? This has to be using Powershell 3.0.

I don't need to add or remove restrictions, I'm looking on how to actually enable the handler mapping itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is additional overhead in gathering the site name and what not, but here is the basic code you would need:

```
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/handlers/@AccessPolicy" -Value "Read, Script, Execute" -PSPath "IIS:/sites/Default Web Site"
```

Leave the `-PSPath` part out to do it at the server level.

Remove "Execute" to disable ISAPI-dll.

Also, [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899.aspx) link may serve as a useful reference.

Comment: This helped me in the GUI too, `Edit Feature Permissions` and checking or un-checking `Execute` under `Script` allows to enable or disable.